# How can I check if it's safe to cast to T in an Iterator?

Tags: java, generics, iterator

I would like to implement a custom list with an iterator, to understand it better myself, but I've ran into a problem with generic types, that I am using myself for the first time.
This is the important part of my class

```
public class MyList<T> implements Iterable<T> 
{

// Unrelated code

@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator()
{
    return new Iterator<T>()
    {
        private Node position = firstNode;

        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return position.getNext() != null;
        }

        public T next()
        {
            String current = "";
            if (this.hasNext())
            {
                current = position.getData();
                position = position.getNext();
            }
            return (T) current;
```

Here Eclipse says that this is an unchecked cast, so I tried changing it to:

```
            return (T) (current instanceof T?current:null);
```

But then Eclipse gives an error: "Cannot perform instanceof check against type parameter T. Use its erasure Object instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime"

What do I do to get rid of the warning without using @SupressWarnings?

```
        }

        public void remove()
        {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    };
}

    //unrelated code
}
```

Comment: why make it generic if it's always going to be of type String?

Comment: You cannot safely cast an String to a T! You perhaps need `Node<T>` with getters returning a `T`

Comment: What do you have against using @SuppressWarnings? That's what it's *for.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of all of the casting and `instanceof` by generifying `Node`.

Something like:

```
class Node<T> {
  private Node<T> next;
  private T data;

  public Node<T> getNext () {
    return next;
  }

  public T getData () {
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Had to cange quite a lot, because my node isn't that simple, but now I have 0 warnings (OCD much :p), thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`instanceof` is a runtime check, so because of type erasure compiler cannot know if it can perform the check.

And similarly with your casting example - how can you know that you can perform this cast, if you don't know what type your program will use? This would likely result in a `ClassCastException`.

EDIT:
According to the comment and your last question

> What do I do to get rid of the warning without using @SupressWarnings?

Well, your `current` is a `String`. Don't cast it to an unknown type at all.
Hope it helps and explains more.

Comment: This is not an answer - it should be a comment.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon why it's not an answer? Seriously, maybe I'm too new here

Comment: You are explaining what the problem is - not answering the question. I may well be wrong though - it's just a comment after all. :)

Comment: Maybe you're right, I improved my answer a bit, is it better now? Thanks.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon As one old curmudgeon to another, it seems to me that explaining what the problem is *does* answer the question. Much more so than just providing some working code, for example.

Comment: EJP - that's what I think, too.
However OldCurmudgeon was also right, in the end I didn't answer the question, which was at the end of the post.
Anyway guys, thanks for your advices and comments. Have a nice day!